# Multiplication of Gurobi Linear Expression with a constant

Tags: python, gurobi

How do I multiply a Linear expression with a constant? I have written the code but it always returns `0.0`.

Need help in multiplying a constant with a linear expression.

```
from gurobipy import LinExpr , GRB, Model, quicksum

TimePeriod = [1]
model = Model()
Vars = dict()

def creatingvarriables():
    for t in TimePeriod:
        Vars["y_" + str(t)] = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY,name="y_" + str(t))
        lhs = Vars["y_" + str(t)]
        lhs = LinExpr()
        model.update()                

        #expr1 = LinExpr(2.0*x)
        expr = LinExpr(2.0)
        model.update()


        #print lhs
        #print type(lhs1)

        Vars["y_" + str(t)] = lhs*expr            

        model.update()

        #print lhs
        #print lhs1                
        #print (Vars["y_"+ str(t)]*expr)
        print (Vars["y_"+ str(t)])


creatingvarriables()
```

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR - This is not the way gurobi is used, see code example at the bottom

Let's first go over some code lines -

```
Vars["y_" + str(t)] = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY,name="y_" + str(t))
```

The `model.addVar` method adds a new variable named y_1, which you store in the dictionary `Vars`.

```
lhs = Vars["y_" + str(t)]
```

This creates a new (python) variable, `lhs`, and points it to the gurobi variable you created before (y_0). Note that since you didn't call `model.update()` yet, y_1 can not be used in any expression at this point.

```
lhs = LinExpr()
```

I assume you wanted to create the linear expression `1*y_1 + 0`, but this line doesn't do it.

`LinExpr()` creates a new **empty** linear expression, equivalent to`0*y_1 + 0`. That's because you didn't supply any argument to the constructor of the LinExpr object (documentation for the constructor [here](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/py_linexpr2.html)), so gurobi does not know **which** expression you want, and defaults to zero .

Instead, you can call `LinExp(lhs)`, which will create the expression you wanted. You can then multiply it by 2 by typing `lhs = 2 * lhs`, or even create the end expression directly using `LinExp([2], [Vars["y_" + str(t)]])` - here the first argument is a list of coefficients, and the second one is a list of gurobi variables.

However, gurobi has a very convenient syntax for creating expressions (using [operator overloading](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames)), so you usually shouldn't explicitly call the constructor of LinExpr yourself, but rather use the gurobi variables directly in mathematical expressions.

Here's a simple working code -

```
from gurobipy import Model
model = Model()
var = model.addVar(name="x")
model.update()
print 2 * var
```

Which prints

```
<gurobi.LinExpr: 2.0 x>
```

Comment: As an aside, take a look at [Python's style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?) for conventions on choosing variable and function names.